# jquery cookie help needed (need help forming a cookie)

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I was wondering if it was possible to create a cookie (using jquery.cookie) which looks like this in php:

```
$_COOKIE['124']['ctns'] => 12
$_COOKIE['124']['units'] => 2
```

OR

```
$_COOKIE['124'] => array( 'ctns' => 12, 'units' => 2 )
```

Currently I've created the cookie which looks like:

```
$_COOKIE['124-ctns'] => 12
$_COOKIE['124-units'] => 2
```

But I'm realising that's not going to work for what I need.

The code I'm using (jquery) is:

```
$.cookie('124-ctns', 12, { path: '/' });
$.cookie('124-units', 2, { path: '/' });
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create a multi-dimensional array using jquery cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Cookies ONLY store strings, not objects.
You can convert the objects to JSON so the code looks something like

```
$_COOKIE['124'] => json_encode(array( 'ctns' => 12, 'units' => 2 ));

n124 = JSON.parse($.cookie('124'));
```

Then the variable n124 should be the object so you can get the variables like
    n124.ctns
    n124.units

Answer (score 1):

To create multi-dimensional cookies in PHP:

```
setcookie("124[ctns]",12,time()+3600);
setcookie("124[units]",2,time()+3600);
```

The last parameter is the expiration time.

To access multi-dimensional cookies in PHP:

```
$ctns = $_COOKIE['124']['ctns']; // $ctns will equal 12
$units = $_COOKIE['124']['units']; // $units will equal 2
```

Quick, `print_r($_COOKIE)` will output:

```
Array
(
    [124] => Array
        (
            [ctns] => 12
            [units] => 2
        )

)
```

In short, yes, you can. The following shows a specific example from the PHP manual.

[Example #3 setcookie() and arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: I'm trying to create a cookie in jquery, but as a multidimensional array I guess :)

Comment: I've updated it as such. There is more documentation about multi-dimensional cookies in the link I provided.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get the jquery cookie script to create the multiple dimension array, not php :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
<input name="cb[1]" type="checkbox" value = "1">
<input name="cb[2]" type="checkbox" value = "2">

<javascript>
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    name =  $(this).attr('name');
    val = $(this).val();
    $.cookie(name, val);
});
</javascript>
```

Output when using print_r(cb):

```
[cb] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
```

But now my problem is how to access the stored cookies @.@